# Setting up AWS IoT using Serverless Framework for Multiple IoT Devices

Tags: aws-cloudformation, iot, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-iot

My goal is to create a system on AWS using the [serverless framework](http://serverless.com/) for multiple IoT devices to send JSON payloads to AWS IoT, which in turn will be saved to DynamoDB.

I am very new to using AWS outside of creating EC2 servers and this is my first project using the [serverless framework](http://serverless.com/).

After referring to [an example](https://serverless.zone/iot-with-the-serverless-framework-e228fae87be), the modified version that I came up with is posted below.

**Problem:** It appears that the example is for just 1 device to connect to AWS IoT, which I concluded from the hardcoded IoT Thing certificate being used, such as

```
SensorPolicyPrincipalAttachmentCert:
  Type: AWS::IoT::PolicyPrincipalAttachment
  Properties:
    PolicyName: { Ref: SensorThingPolicy }
    Principal: ${{custom.iotCertificateArn}}

SensorThingPrincipalAttachmentCert:
  Type: "AWS::IoT::ThingPrincipalAttachment"
  Properties:
    ThingName: { Ref: SensorThing }
    Principal: ${self:custom.iotCertificateArn}
```

If this conclusion is correct that `serverless.yml` is configured for only 1 Thing, then what modifications can we make such that more than 1 Thing can be used?

Maybe setup all the Things outside of `serverless.yaml`? Which means removing just `SensorPolicyPrincipalAttachmentCert` and `SensorThingPrincipalAttachmentCert`?

Also, how should we set the `Resource` property to in `SensorThingPolicy`? They are currently set to `"*"`, is this too broard? Or is there a way to limit to just Things.

**serverless.yml**

```
service: garden-iot

provider:
name: aws
runtime: nodejs6.10
region: us-east-1

# load custom variables from a file
custom: ${file(./vars-dev.yml)}

resources:
Resources:
    LocationData:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
        TableName: location-data-${opt:stage}
        AttributeDefinitions:
        - 
            AttributeName: ClientId
            AttributeType: S
        - 
            AttributeName: Timestamp
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
        - 
            AttributeName: ClientId
            KeyType: HASH
        - 
            AttributeName: Timestamp
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1

    SensorThing:
    Type: AWS::IoT::Thing
    Properties:
        AttributePayload:
        Attributes:
            SensorType: soil

    SensorThingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IoT::Policy
    Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
            Action: ["iot:Connect"]
            Resource: ["${self:custom.sensorThingClientResource}"]
            - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: ["iot:Publish"]
            Resource: ["${self:custom.sensorThingSoilTopicResource}"]

    SensorPolicyPrincipalAttachmentCert:
    Type: AWS::IoT::PolicyPrincipalAttachment
    Properties:
        PolicyName: { Ref: SensorThingPolicy }
        Principal: ${{custom.iotCertificateArn}}

    SensorThingPrincipalAttachmentCert:
    Type: "AWS::IoT::ThingPrincipalAttachment"
    Properties:
        ThingName: { Ref: SensorThing }
        Principal: ${self:custom.iotCertificateArn}

IoTRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
        -
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
            Service:
            - iot.amazonaws.com
        Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole

IoTRolePolicies:
Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
Properties:
    PolicyName: IoTRole_Policy
    PolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
        -
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
            - dynamodb:PutItem
        Resource: "*"
        -
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
        Resource: "*"
    Roles: [{ Ref: IoTRole }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 05/09/2018:** I've found this blog post, which describes my approach pretty well: [Ensure Secure Communication with AWS IoT Core Using the Certificate Vending Machine Reference Application](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/iot/ensure-secure-communication-with-aws-iot-core-using-the-certificate-vending-machine-reference-application/)

**--**

You could take a look at [Just-in-Time Provisioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jit-provisioning.html) or build your own solution based on [Programmatic Provisioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/programmatic-provisioning.html).

I have dealt with this topic many times and had to realize that it depends a lot on the use case, which makes more sense. Also security is an aspect to keep an eye on. You don't want to have a public API responsible for JIT device registration accessible by the whole Internet.

A simple Programmatic Provisioning-based scenario could look like this: You build a thing (maybe a sensor), which should be abled to connect to AWS IoT and have an in-house provisioning process.

Simple provisioning process:

1. Thing built
2. Thing has a serial number
3. Thing registers itself via an internal server

The registration code running on the server could look something like this (JS + AWS JS SDK):

```
// Modules
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

// AWS
const iot = new AWS.Iot({ region: process.env.region })

// Config
const templateBodyJson = require('./register-thing-template-body.json')

// registerThing
const registerThing = async ({ serialNumber = null } = {}) => {
  if (!serialNumber) throw new Error('`serialNumber` required!')

  const {
    certificateArn = null,
    certificateId = null,
    certificatePem = null,
    keyPair: {
      PrivateKey: privateKey = null,
      PublicKey: publicKey = null
    } = {}
  } = await iot.createKeysAndCertificate({ setAsActive: true }).promise()
  const registerThingParams = {
    templateBody: JSON.stringify(templateBodyJson),
    parameters: {
      ThingName: serialNumber,
      SerialNumber: serialNumber,
      CertificateId: certificateId
    }
  }
  const { resourceArns = null } = await iot.registerThing(registerThingParams).promise()

  return {
    certificateArn,
    certificateId,
    certificatePem,
    privateKey,
    publicKey,
    resourceArns
  }
}

const unregisterThing = async ({ serialNumber = null } = {}) => {
  if (!serialNumber) throw new Error('`serialNumber` required!')

  try {
    const thingName = serialNumber
    const { principals: thingPrincipals } = await iot.listThingPrincipals({ thingName }).promise()
    const certificates = thingPrincipals.map((tp) => ({ certificateId: tp.split('/').pop(), certificateArn: tp }))

    for (const { certificateId, certificateArn } of certificates) {
      await iot.detachThingPrincipal({ thingName, principal: certificateArn }).promise()
      await iot.updateCertificate({ certificateId, newStatus: 'INACTIVE' }).promise()
      await iot.deleteCertificate({ certificateId, forceDelete: true }).promise()
    }

    await iot.deleteThing({ thingName }).promise()

    return {
      deleted: true,
      thingPrincipals
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Already deleted!
    if (err.code && err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException') {
      return {
        deleted: true,
        thingPrincipals: []
      }
    }

    throw err
  }
}
```

**register-thing-template-body.json:**

```
{
  "Parameters": {
     "ThingName": {
       "Type": "String"
     },
     "SerialNumber": {
       "Type": "String"
     },
     "CertificateId": {
       "Type": "String"
     }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "thing": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
      "Properties": {
        "ThingName": {
          "Ref": "ThingName"
        },
        "AttributePayload": {
          "serialNumber": {
            "Ref": "SerialNumber"
          }
        },
        "ThingTypeName": "NewDevice",
        "ThingGroups": ["NewDevices"]
      }
    },
    "certificate": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
      "Properties": {
        "CertificateId": {
          "Ref": "CertificateId"
        }
      }
    },
    "policy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "DefaultNewDevicePolicy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you got all the "NewDevice" Thing types, groups and policies in place. Also keep in mind ThingName = SerialNumber (important for unregisterThing).